# Flex 4 - How to set Date range in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have a DOB(Date of Birth) and DOJ(Date of Joining) fields in my application. I want to set the DOB DateField range from 1960 to todayDate-20 years. It means how can I set my DOB rangeEnd as (current year(2014) -20 years)?. And How can I set DOJ rangeEnd as (todayDate+7 days)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About add range on date you can proceed in this way:

I suppose your DateField component calls DOB:

You can set a range with `selectableRange` property using `rangeStart` and `rangeEnd` properies, in this way:

```
this.DOB.selectableRange = {rangeStart:new Date(1960,01,01), rangeEnd: new Date()};
```

to accomplish your request you can do:

```
var today:Date = new Date();
var currentYear = today.fullYear;
var currentMonth = today.month;
var currentDay = today.date;
var start20yago:Date = new Date(currentYear - 20, 1, 1);

var after7Days:Date = today["date"] + 7;

this.DOB.selectableRange = {rangeStart:start20yago, rangeEnd: after7Days};
```

Comment: My question is how to set rangeEnd as (current year -20 years)for DOB and the DOJ rangeEnd as (todayDate+7 days)?

Comment: But I have to use this in DateField control. Could you please expand it?

Comment: @user: Hi, what must I expand? DOB is a DateField control. Tell me if you have resolved or expand your answer, so I'll try to help ;)

Comment: sorry. I was in confusion at that time. Now I understand your point.

Comment: @user: Ok, have a nice day ;)